# Laravel initite methods from blade

Tags: laravel, view, laravel-blade

What would be the best design to call functions from Laravel blade. I know calling controllers method from view is a bad design and using a static library would be a solution. But still searching a way to realise the Following:

I have couple of menus and in function of template position I would like to Project those in my view dynamically for example initiate those like

```
{{ showMenu('main') }}
{{ showMenu('sidebar') }}
{{ showMenu('footer') }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set up additional templates with [View Composers](http://laravel.com/docs/responses#view-composers)? You'll be able to take advantage of more flexibility with them.

Comment: Can u give an example how would I proceed with composers? I already use composer in my package to project main data.